# Changing "key" and "values" into "name" and "children" using nest()

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nested

**UPDATE**:
 Solved thanks To @AmeliaBR, that answered my specific question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17416186/d3-nest-key-and-values-conversion-to-name-and-children)  after I asked it.

- [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pleaseteachmehowtodoit/CB38d/) shows the adaptation of the solution to my specific problem.

---

---

**My question was**:

- I'm looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17416186/d3-nest-key-and-values-conversion-to-name-and-children) without changing the structure of the functions I want to use.
- [This](http://jsfiddle.net/9FqKS/) works great if you have defined parents inside the structure, but I can't get access to it.

What I ideally would do is to also do it work efficiently, and I think that in order to do so `nest()` might be a good answer.

I want to change

```
"key": "keyname", "values":"a value"
```

into

```
"name": "keyname", "children":"a value"
```

And in the leaf node change (if possible making the rest of useless data dissapear)

```
 "value": "a value"
```

into

```
"size": "a value"
```

---

I got a bit sad when I read this:

"I don't see any other method than going trough all elements recursively and changing names, which requires copying and deleting each field. However you can always use the source code of nest() as inspiration."

Can you beat that guy with your knowledge?

Comment: How is your question different from [the one you linked to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17416186/d3-nest-key-and-values-conversion-to-name-and-children)?  And why can't you use the approach given in the answer there?

Comment: @AmeliaBR I do not want to change the source code because I have different calls to the same function with different data structures, and I think that is a better way to work manipulating the data rather than changing the source code. Also as I want different plots, I do not want to enter inside every function in order to adapt them to my data.

The question is similar, I am asking for an approach like
 "2)convert your JSON structure to fit the example with Array.map()." that I've been unable to do and was not answered in that question.

Comment: The accepted answer was maybe a little unclear in terminology.  It does not require changing the source code of d3, only changing the specific visualization script **by using the [accessor functions of the treemap layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Treemap-Layout) for their intended purpose** -- to indicate the names of the variables you want to use.  I'm marking this for closure as duplicate, I'll add an answer on the original question so everything is in one place.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you say. I was wrong in my explanation. Ok, my question is a duplicate of the unanswered "2)" there. I could not ask for more information there because I don't have 50 rep. Sorry for duplicate.

Comment: Understood. I don't like the fact that new users can't leave comments -- it only forces them to either ask duplicate questions or create an "answer" on an existing question that is really just a comment.  Anyway, see my answer on the other question, you should be able to adapt it.

Comment: @AmeliaBR Thank you very much. I've learnt a lot and works just as expected. Should I delete the question or leave it like this?

Comment: Either way.  There's some value to having it in the database, marked as a duplicate, since someone might enter search terms that come up with this page but not the other, and that would help them find the answers.  But if you want to tidy up your profile to not have unanswered or closed questions, that's fine too.