# # treemap.children([children])

Tags: d3.js, treemap

I was wondering the correct way to use the child accessor function in d3 pack layout. Creating a nested hierarchy from a flat array but the result uses "values" instead of "children" and the pack layout expects "children". I am aware the question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23345973/changing-key-and-values-into-name-and-children-using-nest) but not sure how to apply the answer. An example would be appreciated for instance I tried to override the function definition like so

```
function children(d){
return d.values;
}
```

Which did not work when I tried to use it here, d3 does not recognize the children so there is no valid cx, cy attributes

```
var diameter2 = 500,
    format = d3.format(",d"),
    dataSource = 2;
var pack = d3.layout.pack()
    .size([diameter2 - 4, diameter2 - 4])
    .value(function(d) { return d.size; });
var svg2 = d3.select("#selection").append("svg")
    .attr("width", diameter2)
    .attr("height", diameter2)

var data = {
"key": "flare",
 values:[{"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
        {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
      {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
      {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}]
      };
function children(d){
return d.values;}

var vis = svg2.datum(data).selectAll(".node")
    .data(pack.nodes)
   .enter()
    .append("g");

var titles = vis.append("title")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; }); 

var circles = vis.append("circle")
    .attr("stroke", "none")
    .style("fill", function(d) { return !d.children ? "tan" : "none"; })
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; });


    if (dataSource == 0)
        pack.value(function(d) { return d.size; });
    if (dataSource == 1)
        pack.value(function(d) { return 100; });
    if (dataSource == 2)
        pack.value(function(d) { return 1 +
                 Math.floor(Math.random()*301); });

    var data1 = pack.nodes(data);

    titles.attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
        .text(function(d) { return d.name +
            (d.children ? "" : ": " + format(d.value)); });

    circles.transition()
        .duration(5000)
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
        .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; });
        }
```

Comment: Looks like it should work. Can't really tell you more without a complete example.

Comment: Added more code, its still under construction but this part runs when I change "values" to "children". I would like to do the data loading dynamically hence the need for d3.nest but that returns "values"

Comment: Your pack layout should be defined as `d3.layout.pack().size([diameter2 - 4, diameter2 - 4]).value(function(d) { return d.size; }).children(function(d){ return d.values; });`

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed. Wish I had come here earlier, could have saved me an evening but where is the fun in that eh? Thank you very much