# Converting into a hierarchical array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, d3.js

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZGgqz/9/)

I want to convert this JSON data

```
var data = [
  {
    "computer": 24,
    "brand": "Italy A",
    "phone": 0,
    "country": "Italy"
  },
  {
    "brand": "Italy C",
    "computer": 0,
    "phone": 0,
    "country": "Italy"
  },
  {
    "brand": "Brazil B",
    "computer": 0,
    "phone": 22,
    "country": "Brazil"
  },
  {
    "computer": 0,
    "brand": "Brazil D",
    "phone": 62,
    "country": "Brazil"
  },
  {
    "computer": 34,
    "brand": "US E",
    "phone": 41,
    "country": "US"
  }
];
```

into a hierarchical form for a `d3` graph:

```
{
  "name": "categories",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "phone",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "US",
          "children": [
            {
              "brand": "US E",
              "size": 41
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Brazil",
          "children": [
            {
              "brand": "Brazil B",
              "size": 22
            },
            {
              "brand": "Brazil D",
              "size": 62
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Italy",
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "computer",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "US",
          "children": [
            {
              "brand": "US E",
              "size": 34
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Brazil",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Italy",
          "children": [
            {
              "brand": "Italy A",
              "size": 24
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I came up with this code to generate the format:

```
function group_children(data){
    var categories = ["phone","computer"];
    var countries = ["US","Brazil","Italy"];
    var object = {name:"categories",children:[]};
    for(var c =0; c < categories.length;c++){
      object.children.push({"name":categories[c],children:[]});

     for(var con = 0;con < countries.length;con++){
       object.children[c].children.push({"name":countries[con],"children":[]});
     }
    }

    for(var i = 0;i < data.length;i++){
     var row = data[i];
     for(var c =0; c < categories.length;c++){
      for(var con = 0;con < countries.length;con++){
        var cat_key = categories[c],
            country_key = countries[con];
        if(row[cat_key] > 0){
          if(object.children[c].name == cat_key && row.country == country_key){  object.children[c].children[con].children.push({brand:row["brand"],size:row[cat_key]});        
          }
        }
      }   
    }
 }
 return object;
}
```

Is it possible , during the iteration, not to push a country into the brand or computer's `children` array if the country's `children` array is empty?

For example, these objects should be removed

```
        // computer
        {
          "name": "Brazil",
          "children": []
        }
        // phone:

        {
          "name": "Italy",
          "children": []
        }
```

Here's the part that push each country into each category's children array:

```
    for(var c =0; c < categories.length;c++){
      object.children.push({"name":categories[c],children:[]});

     for(var con = 0;con < countries.length;con++){
       object.children[c].children.push({"name":countries[con],"children":[]});
     }
    }
```

My approach is probably wrong, so any other suggestions converting the data into that hierarchical form is also appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tL6Lkj1k/10/), is this what you're looking for? I decided to go for a different approach to the one you followed, hope you don't mind. I've commented the code so that it's clearer:

```
var result = {
    name: "categories",
    children: [{
        "name": "phone",
            "children": []
    }, {
        "name": "computer",
            "children": []
    }]
};

$.each(data, function (index, item) {// Go through data and populate the result object.
    if (+item.computer > 0) { // Computer has items.
        filterAndAdd(item, result.children[1], "computer");
    }
    if (+item.phone > 0) { // Phone has items.
        filterAndAdd(item, result.children[0], "phone");
    }
});

function filterAndAdd(item, result_place, type) {// Search and populate.
    var i = -1;
    $.each(result_place.children, function (index,a) {
        if( a.name === item.country ) {
            i = index;
            return false;
        }
    });

    if (i > -1) {// Country already exists, add to children array.
        result_place.children[i].children.push({
            "brand": item.brand,
                "size": item[type]
        });
    } else {// Country doesn't exist, create it.
        result_place.children.push({
            "name": item.country,
                "children": [{
                "brand": item.brand,
                    "size": item[type]
            }]
        });
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `d3.nest()` function to group array elements hierarchically. The documentation is available 
[here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_nest). Also go through [this](http://www.d3noob.org/2014/02/grouping-and-summing-data-using-d3nest.html) tutorial which could definitely help you to create hierarchical data.

That's not enough, you get hierarchical data in terms of key and value pairs. But if you want to convert into name and children, already a question on SO is asked, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17416186/d3-nest-key-and-values-conversion-to-name-and-children).

Answer (score 0):

With your current approach you should iterate the data to find the empty ones, before pushing the countries, which would result in way more iteration than just simply iterating the result at the end to filter the empty ones.

Otherwise you should create the scruture in the same iterations of the data insertion, thus reducing the iterations to 1.