# Changing labels of json for d3 sunburst diagram

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I am trying to use this [code](https://strongriley.github.io/d3/ex/sunburst.html) from sunburst diagram to work for my data. Originally my data is from csv which I have converted to json with the help of d3.nest()

```
   d3.csv("chord.csv", function(error,csv_data){
         var sunData1 = {"key": "KINGDOM", "values": d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { return d.KINGDOM; })
        .key(function(d) { return d.PHYLUM; })
        .key(function(d) { return d.CCLASS; })
        .key(function(d) { return d.ORDER; })
        .key(function(d) { return d.FAMILY; })
        .key(function(d) { return d.GENUS; })
        .rollup(function(v) {return  v.length;})
        .entries(csv_data) 
        };
```

This gives me labels like

```
[{"key":"Animalia","values":[{"key":"Chordata","values":[{"key":"Mammalia","values":[{"key":"Chiroptera","values":[{"key":"Vespertilionidae","values":[{"key":"Myotis","values":496},
```

But in the example, the labels are name, children and size

By assistance from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17416186/d3-nest-key-and-values-conversion-to-name-and-children) I am using the map(function) to change the label to desired as in flare.json. The code for that is here

```
        var sunData2 = {"name":"KINGDOM", "children": sunData1.values.map(function (kingdom){
                return {"name":kingdom.key,  "children": kingdom.values.map(function(phylum){
                   return {"name":phylum.key, "children": phylum.values.map(function(cclass){
                       return{"name":cclass.key, "children": cclass.values.map(function(order){
                           return {"name":order.key, "children": order.values.map(function(family){
                               return {"name":family.key, "children": family.values.map(function(genus){
                                  return {"name":genus.key, "children": genus.values};
                               })};
                           })};
                       })};
                   })};     
                })};
        })};
```

Now, I am able to change it into the desired format, but now it is changing the size  which is "values" in my json  into "children" like here

```
 {"name":"KINGDOM","children":[{"name":"Animalia","children":[{"name":"Chordata","children":[{"name":"undefined","children":[{"name":"Chiroptera","children":[{"name":"Vespertilionidae","children":[{"name":"Myotis","children":496},
```

So, I am looking for some suggestions so that I can change the "children" referring to the count to something distinct, which I can then map in my visualization code.

Issue resolved, I have to delete the data files and comments referring to the data files

Comment: @Cyril  have added the data file

Comment: I am sorry for confusion. Actually I want the children size to have a different label. So that I can assign that value to the size of the arc. I mean,, At the moment it has "name", "children" and "children" with the size values. I am trying to get a different label to the size value instead of  children. If this value will be distinct then I will able to map it to the arc sizes in the partition layout. Like here https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1093025  where name, children and size have distinct label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I am able to get your question correct when you say
*I am trying to get a different label to the size value instead of children*:

But here is my attempt to give **count** to each node and use it for drawing the arcs:

```
function makeSize(json){
  if (json.children instanceof Array){
    json.count = json.children.length;//if array make it count equal to child count
    json.children.forEach(function(d){
      makeSize(d);//call recursive for all children
    });
  } else {
    if (isFinite(json.children))
      json.count = json.children;//if number store that in the count
    else
      json.count = 0;//if nothing make the count 0
  }
}
```

Click on count radio.

Comment: could you please remove all the links to the original data please including json.

Comment: i have removed the fiddle.